To find angular momentum of a circular hoop
A circular hoop of radius 0.3cm has moment of inertia 0.09 kg-m^2 about its axis, makes 10 revolutions per second. Find its angular momentum about its axis and the force that increases the angular momentum by 30% in 10 seconds.
Is the hoop in this question supposed to be taken as a flywheel? And how is the angular momentum and force found? I just cant find any hints on the internet...

Imagine it as a flywheel with all its mass at the rim. The formulae for angular momentum etc will be similar to the formulae of a mass whirling on the end of a light string.

Angular momentum can be computed according to the relation:
$$L=I\omega,$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertial and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.
One can also use the relationship for impulse to talk about the relation between force and momentum:
$$\Delta L=\tau\Delta t.$$
